# Fine-tune Openai GPT - Set general instructions?

Tags: openai-api, gpt-3

I want to make GPT summarise paragraphs. So far I'm sending him a prompt like this:

```
Please summarize each of the 7 paragraphs below into 7 new summarized paragraphs 
containing no more than 40 words.

Parragraph1: fadsfas
Parragraph2: fadsfa
...
```

I'm not using any fine-tuned model so far, but I'd like to, mainly because it will cost less to run the queries and it is supposed to be faster.

I've tried training the model by providing a set of "prompts" with paragraphs and a set of "completions" with their summaries, but the fine-tuned model doesn't work well.

I assume I didn't train the model in the correct way.

Isn't there a way to provide the fine-tuning process with a set of "instructions" together with the set of prompts + completions?

How would GPT know if I want paragraphs to never exceed a certain number of words for example?

I have the impression that the dataset might not be enough to provide enough instructions to GPT on how to process the input.

Should I just send this in every prompt that I use for the training?

```
{
  "prompt": "Please summarize each of the 7 paragraphs below into 7 
              new summarized paragraphs containing no more than 40 words.
    
              Parragraph1: ...."
  "completion": "..."
}
```